# How to print only Machine Accounts with pdbedit?

Tags: linux, samba

Using `pdbedit`, I can use `--list` to list all Samba entities in the NT4 domain - users and computers. What I need to do is list **only** the Machine accounts - accounts that end in a `$` (i.e. `Computer-01$`).

How can I do that? Using Samba 4.2.14 on Debian Jessie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What I need to do is list only the Machine accounts - accounts that end in a $

You can do this with grep:

```
pdbedit --list | grep "\$$"
```

This will match all lines ending in a literal `$` character.

Comment: Argh... I assume it has to do with RegEx characters in that case... That worked, thanks!